# GameScene nodes not appearing in SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to get some nodes to display on screen.

In my GameViewController, I have:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            // Alternative -> let scene = GameScene(size: view.frame.size)
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "AntarcticaScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }
}
```

And in my file called AntarcticaScene.swift, I have:

```
class AntarcticaScene: SKScene {

    var box: SKSpriteNode!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        // Initialize entities
        box = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.cyan, size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 60))

        print("Game scene loading")

        // Add entities
        addChild(box)

        // Set positions
        box.position.x = size.width  / 2
        box.position.y = size.height / 2
    }
}
```

I also have an `AntarcticaScene.sks` file with the Custom Class set to `AntarcticaScene`. This sks file has a red square on the center of the screen.

Right now, when I run the application, I can see the red square from the sks file but I don't understand why the blue box won't appear on the screen, even though my print statement is being executed.

Comment: I am having the same problem. If you got it do you think you can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things...

set a zPosition on all objects

```
box = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.cyan, size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 60))
box.zPosition = 1
addChild(box)
```

the default anchorPoint for a scene is 0,0 (which is the center of the screen) unless changed that means that through your positioning you are adding the box to the top right corner and 3/4 of the box will be out of view.

try setting the box to a location in view to ensure that it shows up

```
box.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `self.size.width` instead of  `size.width`.